# Problem transforming XML with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am having problem transforming xml to xml using xsl. I found out where the problem comes from but still don't know how to fix it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tells uri="" xmlns="http://dl.kr.org/dig/2003/02/lang">
  <impliesc>
    <catom name="name1"/>
    <catom name="name2"/>
  </impliesc>
  <impliesc>
    <catom name="name3"/>
    <catom name="name4"/>
  </impliesc>
</tells>
```

I think the problems comes from this line

```
<tells uri="" xmlns="http://dl.kr.org/dig/2003/02/lang">
```

If I remove the "uri="" xmlns="http://dl.kr.org/dig/2003/02/lang"" and leave only the

```
"<tells>"
```

everything works perfectly. But is there a way to transform it without removing it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:element name="tells">

        <xsl:for-each select="./tells/impliesc">

            <xsl:element name="impliesc">

                <xsl:for-each select="./tells/impliesc/catom">

                    <xsl:element name="catom">

                        <xsl:attribute name="name">
                            <xsl:value-of select="./tells/impliesc/individual/@name"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>

                     </xsl:element>

                </xsl:for-each>

            </xsl:element>

        </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:element>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Can you show a bit of your transform?

Comment: You may post your XSLT sheet to help us find the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct:  the reason your transformation isn't working is that you have a namespace declaration on the `tells` element.

To make this particular problem go away, you need to make your XSLT aware of the namespace, and tell it that the `tells` element that it's trying to transform belongs to that namespace.  The most common way to do this is to declare a namespace prefix in the `xsl:stylesheet` element, and then use that prefix in the XPath, e.g.:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:n="http://dl.kr.org/dig/2003/02/lang" ... >
   ...
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <output>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="//n:tells"/>
      </output>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="n:tells">
      ...
   </xsl:template>

<xsl:stylesheet>
```

The `xmlns:n` attribute at the top of the stylesheet tells the XSLT processor that the 'http://dl.kr.org/dig/2003/02/lang' namespace exists, and that the `n:` prefix is an abbreviation for it.  In the `select` and `match` attributes, the `n:` prefix tells the XSLT processor that when it's looking for elements named `tells`, it should look for elements with that name that are in the `http://dl.kr.org/dig/2003/02/lang` namespace.

XML namespaces are an essential part of XML technologies, and people often overlook them when they're learning XML - they're complicated and not very intuitive, and you can ignore them for quite a while when you're coming up to speed on XML.  But there comes a point where you can no longer afford the simplifying assumption that namespaces don't exist, and you're at that point.

Comment: In `<xsl:template match="n:tells">`, do not forget that every node in XPath will have to bear the `n:` prefix. For example: `n:impliesc/n:catom[@name='name1']`.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with namespaces you have to declare them in your transform; otherwise you won't be able to select the document nodes correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Well without seeing your XSLT code we can't fix it. Nevertheless, the `xmlns="http://dl.kr.org/dig/2003/02/lang"` means the `tells` elements and its descendant elements are in that namespace so your XSLT needs to take that into account. With XSLT 1.0 your stylesheet needs to bind a prefix to the namespace URI and use that prefix in XPath expressions and XSLT match patterns to qualify element names e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:df="http://dl.kr.org/dig/2003/02/lang"
  exclude-result-prefixes="df"
  version="1.0">

  <-- examples -->
  <xsl:template match="df:tells">
    <foo>
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </foo>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="df:impliesc">
    <bar>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="df:catom[1]"/>
    </bar>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```